A film about a boy, a girl, an old woman and crossing time dimensions
I watched this film a long time ago and I remember the plot so vaguely.  I think it was before 2000, maybe in English, but I'm not sure because I watched it translated.
A 16-17 years old boy is the main character of this film, he has a vacation and his parents send him to their relative's house. This is a big, beautiful house and its hostess is a mysterious old lady who never gets out from her room. This guy only contacts the servants.
Every night he meets one girl who does appear in the house at daytime. Night after night it seems that time is passing for this girl faster than for the boy and the girl is becoming older, getting married and for the boy it is just a few days. Once this night adventures stop, the boy gets sad about it and he discovers that the old lady, the hostess of this house, is this girl from his night walks. 
Can someone recognize this film?

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year\decade? The country\language? Where\when did you see it? This could really help us out.

no, I don't remember. I think it was before 2000, maybe English, but I'm not sure because that I watched translated

Also, a similar (and possibly duplicate) question here.

Sounds like the plot of Tom's Midnight Garden. It was adapted several times, but based on your data, I'm guessing you meant the film from 1999.

When Tom Long's brother Peter gets measles he is sent to stay with his Uncle Alan and Aunt Gwen in a flat with no garden. An elderly and reclusive landlady, Mrs Bartholomew, lives upstairs. Because he may be infectious he is not allowed out to play, and feels lonely. Without exercise he is less sleepy at night and when he hears the communal grandfather clock strangely strike 13, he investigates and finds the small back yard is now a large sunlit garden. Here he meets another lonely child called Hatty, who seems to be the only one who can see him. They have adventures which he gradually realises are taking place in the 19th century. Each night when Tom visits, Hatty is slightly older and Tom begins to wonder about the nature of time and reality. In an attempt to discover what's going on Tom asks Hattie to leave her skates in a hidden place. When he goes back into the future he manages to find them. One night Hatty and Tom go out skating however Hatty begins to fall in love with a boy from her own time named Barty and Tom finds he is invisible to her. The next night Tom is unable to find the garden, running into rubbish bins from the modern day instead. Just before Tom returns home he meets Mrs Bartholomew, who is revealed to be an elderly Hatty.

The trailer is below. If it doesn't seem familiar, let me know; the BBC also aired several adaptations.



